# Remove spam referals from Google Analytics organic traffic report

Tags: google-analytics, spam, referrer, google-analytics-spam

I've got some referral spam showing up in my Google Analytics organic traffic. Usually I just ignore it but because it's showing up in my organic traffic and it's pushing up my bounce rate as the referral spam has a 90-100% bounce rate whereas my normal traffic has a 40% bounce rate.

How can I remove the referral spam, from being tracked? The spam referral search phrases are:

- `с.новым.годом.рф`
- `how.to.travel.and.make.money.online.for.free.with.maps.ilovevitaly.com`

Comment: I thought there'd been a few questions regarding referral spam in GA and methods to block it... could try here... http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/75909/how-to-fight-off-referrer-spammers

Comment: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/82471/can-organic-traffic-be-spoofed-in-google-analytics-the-same-way-as-refer-spam and http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/75909/how-to-fight-off-referrer-spammers